# I cannot copy files to my Android MTP files or my pen drives

Tags: usb, mount, mtp

I plug in my pen-drive and it copies a few files before nemo freezes and shuts down. And the data remains partially copied.
I have been looking around for stuff on AskUbuntu. Using [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342319/where-are-mtp-mounted-devices-located-in-the-filesystem), I figured out the mount point was

> /run/user/$UID/gvfs

I tried this [link](https://sharadchhetri.com/2013/12/19/how-to-fix-read-only-usb-pen-drive-in-ubuntu/) from another AskUbuntu [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/826425/cannot-copy-to-usb-every-usb-stick-is-read-only-16-04).

I tried this

> umount /var/run/user/$UID/gvfs

```
umount: /var/run/user/0/gvfs: no mount point specified.
```

Tried this from [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/304747/my-usb-flash-does-not-have-write-permission-i-cant-copy-files-into-it-via-na))

> sudo chmod 777 -R /var/run/user/$UID/gvfs/*

Nor did the accepted answer
Considering the device name if GT P5100

Comment: `getfacl /media/$USER ` please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I have been using Nemo as a file explorer and it doesn't seem to work when I use Nemo.
When I switched to Nautilus temporarily, the files transferred sucessfully.